# Mapping AWS glue table columns to target RDS instance table columns

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-glue

```
    i have created a glue job, that takes data from S3 bucket and insert into **RDS postgres instance**.
```

In the S3 bucket I have created different folder (partition).
 Can I  map different columns in different partitions to same target RDS instance?

Answer (score 0):

When you say partition in s3, is it indicated using the hive style ?? eg: bucket/folder1/folder2/partion1=xx/partition2=xx/partition3=yy/..

If so, you shouldnt be storing data with different structures of information in s3 partitions and then mapping them to a single table. However if its just data in different folders, like s3://bucket/folder/folder2/folder3/.. and these are actually genuinely different datasets, then yes it is possible to map those datasets to a single table. However you cannot do it via the ui. You will need to read these datasets as separate dynamic/data frames and join them using a key in glue/spark and load them to rds